Irreducible components of a closed subspace $C \subseteq X$ is precisely $ \{ C \cap Z_i \} $ where $Z_i$ are the irreducible component of $X$?
Let $X$ be a topological space with finite irreducible components $Z_1, \dots , Z_n$. Let $C\subseteq X$ be a  closed subspace. Then the irreducible components of $C$ is precisely
$$ \{ C \cap Z_i : C \cap Z_i \neq \varnothing \} $$
?
I think that it is true if $C$ is open ( Why are the irreducible components of a subspace of Noetherian space just the intersection with the irreducible components? ) but how about the case that $C$ is closed ? I looked for related data but couldn't find any similar questions.
( Can be skipped ) Originally I wanted to prove next statement from algebraic geometry : Let $f: Z \to T$ be a proper flat morphism from reduced scheme to the spectrum of a discrete valuation ring, then its closed fiber $f^{-1}(t)$ ( $t \in T$ closed ) has irreducible components $\{ f^{-1}(t) \cap Z_i : f^{-1}(t) \cap Z_i \neq \varnothing \} $ , where $Z_i$ are the irreducible components of $Z$.

If I understand correctly what you are asking this is clearly false. Let $X$ be the affine line with the Zariski topology. It is irreducible. Let $C$ be a reducible subspace of $X$, e.g. 2 distinct points.

Do you want to assume every component of $C$ has the same dimension as $X$, or something similar?

Another counter-example: $\mathbb N$ with the cofinite topology is irreducible, but its closed, discrete subspace ${1,2}$ has two irreducible components.

@Lazzaro Campeotti : O.K. Thank you. And, I posted a question about proof that I am currently struggling with, which is where this question originated. Perhaps, can you please take a look?

@Ulli :  O.K. Thank you for simple counter example ~

@LazzaroCampeotti  : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4943270/gortz-wedhorn-algebraic-geometry-proof-of-proposition-14-121. ..
