Gortz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry, proof of Proposition 14.123
I want to understand next statement ( in proof of Proposition 14.123 of Gortz's Algebraic Geometry book ):

Let $T$ be the spectrum of discrete valuation ring, $\eta \in T$ the generic point, $t\in T$ the closed point, and $f: Z\to T$ a proper flat morphism such that the fiber $f^{-1}(\eta)$ has dimension $0$. Then the special fiber $f^{-1}(t)$ has dimension $0$, too.

For this statement, the author argues as follows. First note next Proposition 14.14 and Theorem 14.116 :

Proposition 14.14. Let $Y$ be a Dedekind scheme, let $\eta$ be the generic point of $Y$ and let $f: X\to Y$ be a morphism. Consider the following assertions.

(i) The morphism $f$ is flat
(ii) The scheme $X$ is equal to the schematic closure of the generic fiber $f^{-1}(\eta)$ in $X$.
(iii) Every irreducible component of $X$ dominates $Y$.
Then the implications $"(i) \Leftrightarrow  (ii) \Rightarrow (iii)" $ hold. If $X$ is reduced, all assertions are equivalent.



Theorem 14.116. Let $f: X\to Y$ be an open morphism locally of finite type. Suppose that $Y$ is universally catenary, irreducible and noetherian, that $\dim Y < \infty$, and that $X$ is equidimensional. Assume that the following condition is satisfied.

(D) For every irreducible component $X'$ of $X$ one has
$$ \dim Y = \sup_{y\in f(X')} \dim \mathcal{O}_{Y,y}.$$
( This condition is satisfied for the proper morphism ; C.f. Gortz's book Remark 14.117 - (2) .)
Then for all $y\in f(X)$ the fiber $f^{-1}(y)$ is equidimensional and
$$ \dim X = \dim Y + \dim f^{-1}(y) $$


Second, since $Z_{\operatorname{red}}$ is again flat and proper over $T$ ( use Proposition 14.14 and noting that for a morphism $f$ of finite type, $f$ is proper if and only if $f_{\mathrm{red}}$ is proper  ), and since the dimensions do not change, we may assume that $Z$ is reduced. Applying Proposition 14.14 again, we see that under this assumption all irreducible components of $Z$ are also proper and flat over $T$. Therefore we can apply Theorem 14.116 to each of these and we see that $\dim f^{-1}(t) = \dim f^{-1}(\eta) =0$.
I don't understand the bold statement $\dim f^{-1}(t) = \dim f^{-1}(\eta)$. Let $\iota_i : Z_i \hookrightarrow Z$  ( $ 1 \le i \le n $ ) be the irreducible components of $Z$. Applying the Theorem 14.116 we get for all $i$,
$$\dim Z_i = \dim T + \dim ( f\circ \iota_i)^{-1}(t).$$
$$ \dim Z_i = \dim T + \dim ( f\circ \iota_i)^{-1}(\eta).$$
In particular, $$\dim ( f^{-1}(t) \cap Z_i ) = \dim (f\circ \iota_i)^{-1}(t) = \dim ( f\circ \iota_i)^{-1}(\eta)= \dim (f^{-1}(\eta) \cap Z_i ) $$ for all $i$.
Note that $\{ f^{-1}(\eta) \cap Z_i : f^{-1}(\eta) \cap Z_i \neq \varnothing \}$ forms the irreducible components of $f^{-1}(\eta)$ ( $\because$ Gotrz's book, Exercise 3.17 ( p.92 ) )
If $\{ f^{-1}(t) \cap Z_i : f^{-1}(t) \cap Z_i \neq \varnothing \}$ also forms the irreducible component of $f^{-1}(t)$, then since the dimension of topological space is the supremum of dimensions of its irreducible components, we get $\dim f^{-1}(t) = \dim f^{-1}(\eta)  ( =0 )$. And this bold statement is true? If not, perhaps is there any other route to show the equality of the dimension of special fiber and the dimension of the generic fiber ?

O.K. This questions are about pure general topology, have nothing to do with algebraic geometry ( I feel like a fool :) ). Note that ( Munkres, Topology, Corollary 50.3 )

Corollary 50.3. If the topological space $X$ is a finite union of its closed subspaces ( not supposed irreducible ) $F_1, F_2, \dots, F_n$, then $$ \dim X = \max\{ \dim F_1, \dots , \dim F_n \} .$$

From this, we have
$$ \dim f^{-1}(t) = \max\{ \dim ( f^{-1}(t) \cap Z_1 ), \dots, \dim ( f^{-1}(t) \cap Z_n)\} = \max\{ \dim ( f^{-1}(\eta) \cap Z_1 ), \dots, \dim ( f^{-1}(\eta) \cap Z_n)\} = \dim f^{-1}(\eta)=0.$$
So we are done.
